# Recuperar value de un textarea con Sweet Alert

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert

Tengo un Sweet Alert con un `textarea` pero no consigo recuperar lo que el usuario introduce en el.

```
        this.$swal({
            title: message,
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: {
                cancel: this.capitalize(this.__('cancel')),
                confirm: {
                    text: this.capitalize(this.__("yes, I am sure")),
                    value: true
                },
            },
            content: {
                element: "textarea",
                attributes: {
                    placeholder: "Escriba su motivo ...",
                },
            },
            dangerMode: true
        }).then(async (value) => {
            if (value) {
                console.log(value);
            }
        })
```

El `value` solo me devuelve `true` o `false` (depende de si el usuario acepta o rechaza). Pero en la [documentación](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/) no encuentro una forma de recuperar lo que introduce el usuario. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO**

He añadido un `id` en el atributo `content`:

```
            content: {
                element: "textarea",
                attributes: {
                    placeholder: "Escriba su motivo ...",
                    id: 'allegation_textarea',
                },
            },
```

Después, en la promesa, recojo el valor y listo:

```
const allegation_value = document.getElementById("allegation_textarea").value;
```

Desconozco si hay una mejor solución, pero me ha funcionado bien, y en poco código.